# Is it correct to use the `menu` tag without the `menuitem` tag?

Tags: html

why do *caniuse* considers the html tag `menu` "*well-supported in all browsers effectively*" (http://caniuse.com/#search=HTML4%20elements%20(well-supported%20subset)?

According Mozilla web site, that support from the web browser is rather poor(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu#Browser_compatibility).

Has HTML `menu` tag only sense if (if) it contains nested `menuitem` tag (which has very little support even according caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=menu)?

Thanks.

```html
<p>The following html tag <i>menu</i> actually works in all web browser: is this (without nested <i>menuitem</i> tag) a "proper" use of the tag?</p>
<menu>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li><button>button</button></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Looks only supported by FX: http://caniuse.com/#search=menu - so who would ever want to use it without polyfills or at all?

Comment: It seems like you are asking two things at a time. Can you please put the first question (that does not fit with the title) into a separate SO question?

Comment: These are nice: http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, sorry. Those two questions are linked: if `menu` can be properly (semantically, etc.) used without `menuitem`, then I understand why that difference between caniuse and mozilla, thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks, I mentioned that link in my question;-) I do not understand why they caniuse considers otherwise support the same tag in both its link I mentioned

Comment: Likely an old page never updated since it was created - why not ask caniuse instead: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks. However, if `menu` can also be used without `menuitem`, then it is fair to consider `menu`  itself is well-supported in all web browsers: the code of my snippet, in fact, works in all browsers.

Comment: What other than semantics does it do for you? The menu tag seems to work as a blockquote https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nwLkf2rv/

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the caniuse support page (thanks
@mplungjan for the suggestion): https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3121#issuecomment-274061971

The first link of my original question ("menu element is well-supported") refers to HTML4.